# javaでのtextfield内の文字列取得について

Tags: java, swing

`JTextField text = new JTextField("初期値");`で作成したテキストフィールド内の文字列を`getText`で取得したところ「初期値」をちゃんと取得できていました。しかし、テキストフィールド内の文字列「初期値」を削除したうえで別の文字列を入力し、再度`getText`を行っても取得される文字列は「初期値」のままでした(テキストフィールド内にあらかじめ設定されている文字列しか取得できない)。
どうすればテキストフィールド内の文字列をきちんと取得できるのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。現在、このコードのみでgetTextを行っています。

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
public class registration extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private JPanel contentPane;
  JTextField producttext;
  JTextField pricetext;
  /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                registration frame = new registration();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Create the frame.
   */
  public registration() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);        
    // 商品登録部
    JLabel productlabel = new JLabel("name");
    producttext = new JTextField("");
    productlabel.setBounds(10, 10, 60, 20);
    contentPane.add(productlabel);

    producttext.setBounds(80, 13, 100, 20);
    contentPane.add(producttext);

    JLabel price = new JLabel("price");
    pricetext = new JTextField("");
    price.setBounds(10, 40, 60, 20);
    contentPane.add(price);

    pricetext.setBounds(80, 43, 100, 20);
    contentPane.add(pricetext);

    JButton addbutton = new JButton("登録");
    addbutton.setBounds(80, 70, 60, 30);
    addbutton.addActionListener(new addProduct());
    contentPane.add(addbutton);

  }

  public String[] getTextField(){
    String[] str;
    str = new String[2];

    str[0] = producttext.getText();
    str[1] = pricetext.getText();
    return str;
  }
  public void setTextField(){
    producttext.setText("");
    pricetext.setText("");
  }
}
```

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class addProduct implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String str[];
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        registration gettext = new registration();
        str = gettext.getTextField();

        if(str[0].equals("") && str[1].equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "空欄です","Error!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else if(str[0].equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "nameが空欄です","Error!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else if(str[1].equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "priceが空欄です","Error!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "登録完了","Message", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);    
            gettext.setTextField();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコード](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)が張り付けてあれば、すぐ回答が得られると思います。

Answer (score 1):

`ActionListener`(`addProduct`)内で、新規の別`JFrame`(`registration`)を作成して、`getTextField()`を呼び出しているせいで、常に初期値が表示されています。

例えば、`addProduct`クラスを`registration`クラスの内部クラスにするなどして、現在表示している`registration`の`getTextField()`メソッドを呼び出すように修正してはどうでしょうか。

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class registration extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel contentPane;
    JTextField producttext;
    JTextField pricetext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    registration frame = new registration();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public registration() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        // 商品登録部
        JLabel productlabel = new JLabel("name");
        producttext = new JTextField("");
        productlabel.setBounds(10, 10, 60, 20);
        contentPane.add(productlabel);

        producttext.setBounds(80, 13, 100, 20);
        contentPane.add(producttext);

        JLabel price = new JLabel("price");
        pricetext = new JTextField("");
        price.setBounds(10, 40, 60, 20);
        contentPane.add(price);

        pricetext.setBounds(80, 43, 100, 20);
        contentPane.add(pricetext);

        JButton addbutton = new JButton("登録");
        addbutton.setBounds(80, 70, 60, 30);
        addbutton.addActionListener(new addProduct());
        contentPane.add(addbutton);
    }
    public String[] getTextField() {
        String[] str = new String[2];
        str[0] = producttext.getText();
        str[1] = pricetext.getText();
        return str;
    }
    public void setTextField() {
        producttext.setText("");
        pricetext.setText("");
    }

    class addProduct implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            //String str[];
            //JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            // 新規のregistrationを作成している
            //registration gettext = new registration();
            //str = gettext.getTextField();

            Window frame = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component) event.getSource());
            String[] str = getTextField();

            if (str[0].equals("") && str[1].equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "空欄です", "Error!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else if (str[0].equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "nameが空欄です", "Error!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else if (str[1].equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "priceが空欄です", "Error!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "登録完了", "Message", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                //gettext.setTextField();
                setTextField();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

または、イベントソース(`JButton`)から`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(...)`メソッドなどで親ウィンドウ(このサンプルでは`registration`)を取得して、`gettext.getTextField();`を呼び出しても良いかもしれません。

```
public class addProduct implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Window frame = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component) event.getSource());
        if (frame instanceof registration) {
            registration gettext = (registration) frame;
            String[] str = gettext.getTextField();

            if (str[0].equals("") && str[1].equals("")) {
            //以下省略...
```